# .append not working when calling a php file

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have this function which used to work, but apparently decided to take a dump on me. Does anybody have any idea of what could be wrong?

```
<?php 
require("php/connect.php");
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Clasificados</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
<link type="text/css" href="css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $.post(
        'php/bridge.php', 
        {
            fun:"estados"
        },
        function(answer){
            if(answer){
                $('#estafil').append(answer);
            }
        }
    );

});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left">
<form name="search">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="searchbar">Introduce terminos de busqueda:</label>
        <input type="text" name="searchbar" id="searchbar" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="estafil">Filtrar por estados:</label>
        <select name="estafil" id="estafil" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Inciciar busqueda" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

The php that is called goes something like this:

```
require("connect.php");
session_start();
$fun=$_POST['fun'];
$rol=$_SESSION['rol'];
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
if($fun=="estados"){
   $query="SELECT Nombre FROM estados";
   $extract=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract)){
       echo $row['Nombre'];
   }
}
```

I've tried everything but I really can't pinpoint the problem!

Comment: php, html, and javascript in one file?!

Comment: `#estafil` is a <select> element: are you appending <option> element? what's the content of ajax response? what if you change `echo $row['Nombre'];` with `echo "<option>".$row['Nombre']."</option>";`

Comment: @ScottM. I believe they call it *tag soup* :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup

Comment: tag soup, sounds refreshing to me :)

Comment: @ScottM. Thats just for explanation purposes.

Comment: I also put JS, CSS, and HTML in the same file from time to time. This is often very useful when the content is being loaded through ajax. It makes your ajax pages much more modular. Again, of course there are downsides to this (common code, etc..) but it not **always** a horrible plan,.

Comment: I don't know so much, but I suspect that session_start() line must be before require("php/connect.php")

Comment: @F.Calderan Thanks man! That was it!! I merged my code with someone else's yesterday and the option tags probably got lost in the process. We didn't make a backup because we were pressed for time. I believe I had the option tags in the JS last time, but this works just as well! Thanks!!

Comment: @sgmart That is not the case at all. connect.php only serves as a connection to the database and is independent from the session variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a text. Please try this code

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract)){
        echo '<option>'.$row['Nombre'].'</option>';
    }
```